# Relations between monoids and modules?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, modules, monoid, monoidal-categories

What is the relation between monoids and modules? Are they completely different algebraic structures, or is there a kind of inclusion relation like "elements of a module are also elements of a monoid"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A module is an abelian group.  (It's more useful to think of a module as the analog of a vector space, but with the set of scalars coming from a ring instead of a field.  Usually, one arrives at this notion of a module in terms of "the action of a ring on a set" where the set is a module.)

A monoid is a relaxation of the definition of a group.  A monoid has an associative operation and a neutral element, but makes no promises about inverses.

I don't see how to express any more of a relation than "all modules are monoids" but only for the dull reason that all (abelian) groups are (abelian) monoids with the added constraint that every element has an inverse.

Answer (score 4):

There is a *chain*  of *forgetful* functors which progressively forgets the various operations in the structure: $$\mathrm{Mod_R}\to\mathrm{Ab}\to\mathrm{AbMon}\to\mathrm{Set}$$

The interesting thing is that you can go in the opposite direction too with *free* functors $$\mathrm{Set}\to\mathrm{AbMon}\to\mathrm{Ab}\to\mathrm{Mod_R}$$

Each forgetful functor $U$ is adjoint to the respective free functor $F$